# C&R training in IBM SPSS Modeler

Tags: cart, spss-modeler

I am trying to train a `C&R Tree` in IBM SPSS Modeler. The issue I have is that when I click on the Model nugget (generated model) and view the constructed tree, I see that the algorithm uses only 70% of my data in training the model. I have tried this on multiple data sets and still got the same thing. I Also checked classifiers in SPSS Modeler (e.g. CHAID) but did not face this issue. 
Would highly appreciate you help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The C&R Tree Node is using an "Overfit prevention set", with default value of 30%.

The documentation in "ModelerModelingNodes.pdf" expains this as:

> Overfit prevention set. The algorithm internally separates records
>   into a model building set and an overfit prevention set, which is an
>   independent set of data records used to track errors during training
>   in order to prevent the method from modeling chance variation in the
>   data. Specify a percentage of records. The default is 30.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the previous, please, have in mind, that when constructing a regression, it only allows you to use full records, so if you have empty cells, the algo most likely deletes those records.